# Why is "i" added to donuts[i] in the code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
var donuts = ["jelly donut", "chocolate donut", "glazed donut"];

for (var i = 0; i < donuts.length; i++) {
  donuts[i] += " hole";
  donuts[i] = donuts[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: The `i` allows you to access to the element in a array when the `i` is 0 you are accessing the first item on the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: In the given code, i is used as an index to access each element of the donuts array using the square bracket notation (donuts[i]).

Comment: `i` is not added to `donuts[i]` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

`i` represents the number (`index`) where the element is located in the array. You can notice it `i` is assigned the value of 0 when it is initialized in the `for` loop.

In the first iteration `i` is 0 so it is the same as saying `donuts[0]`, in the next `i` will be 1 (since `i++` is incrementing `i` by 1) we will looking at `donuts[1]` and so on until the `i` is less than the `length` of the array. Once `i` reaches same value as the `length` of the array the condition `i < donuts.length` will not be true anymore, and the `loop` will stop.

Another way to go about looping through every item in the array is using the `forEach` method.
Here is a link talking more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: to put it in simple terms, donut[i] means it's referring to all the index or strings in the array. right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`arr[i]` refers to the (i-1) th element of that array. In this case, the loop goes through all its elements one by one, accessing each one by using the array index operator.

You can read more about arrays in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: So, donuts[i] means it affects all the arrays. Example donut[I] += "hole" means it iterates through the code and adds holes to the strings. right?

Comment: @NAKDICKSON  No  `donuts[i]` just means 1 single donuts item based on the value of `i`, with `i` been the index.  it's the for loop that changes `i` every time that makes it all donuts.

Answer (score 0):

These are references to elements in the JavaScript array which are 0 based.  Here I also add the value of `i` to each.

```js
var donuts = ["jelly donut", "chocolate donut", "glazed donut"];
// reference to the first donut:
console.log("Before:", donuts[0]);
for (var i = 0; i < donuts.length; i++) {
  donuts[i] += " hole " + i;
  donuts[i] = donuts[i].toUpperCase();
}
console.log(donuts);
console.log("After:", donuts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering why the letter I is used, it is possible to say that it refers to the index.